# Steam authorization

Tags: c#, steam

I'm trying to get html code of authorizated steam page, but I can't log in.
My code is

```
public string tryLogin(string EXP, string MOD, string TIME)
{
    var rsa = new RSA();
    string encryptedPass;
    rsa.Exponent = EXP;
    rsa.Modulus = MOD;
    encryptedPass = rsa.Encrypt(Pass);

    string reqString = "username=kasyjack&password=" + encryptedPass + "&emailauth=&kasyjackfriendlyname=&captchagid=&captcha_text=&emailsteamid=&rsatimestamp=" + TIME + "&remember_login=false";
    byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://store.steampowered.com/login/dologin/");
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
    request.Host = "store.steampowered.com";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
    request.CookieContainer = _CookieCont;

    using (Stream st = request.GetRequestStream())
        st.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string RSAR = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return RSAR;
}
```

but response message is

```
{"success":false,"requires_twofactor":false,"clear_password_field":true,"captcha_needed":false,"captcha_gid":-1,"message":"Incorrect login."}
```

So does anyone know, what's wrong with login? Need your help.

Comment: If you use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the html requests and response when you do a normal login, you can then compare it against what your code does.

Comment: Google chrome dev tools - username:kasyjack

Comment: Set-Cookie:steamLogin=76561198277236483%7C%7C5F9A9D14514EBD1716AA252D71BEE6A91455EC39; But if use this instead of login, same response

Comment: I assume that you did a GET to /login first, that was also using the `_CookieCont`? And your EXP, MOD and TIME parameters are coming from a call to `getrsakey`?

Comment: rene yes. 
public CookieContainer _CookieCont = new CookieContainer();
            GetSessiondID();
            var resp = GetRSAKey();
            var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resp);
            string publickey_mod = results.publickey_mod;
            string publickey_exp = results.publickey_exp;
            string timestamp = results.timestamp;
            string token_gid = results.token_gid;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SteamBot repository on GitHub has a working example on how to login to Steam via their website: [link to method](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/blob/master/SteamTrade/SteamWeb.cs#L172).

Here is a diagram explaining the whole process(made by me):

[image: Steam Web Login]